# How to make user created software and folder searchable by Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, zeitgeist

I have created a new folder in home directory, and put a downloaded program in this folder, how to make both this folder and program searchable by the system when using quick launch/search utility?

Comment: I would think you just add it to the system path...

Comment: yeah, thats could be a solution, but how about the folder, why unity cannot find the folder, looks like unity only finds the default ones...

Comment: um, i meant adding the folder to the system path.  not sure if it searches path or just standard /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin, and the like...i should think it just searches the system path.  if that doesn't do it maybe updatedb if it uses the locate database.  if you're home folder is encrypted you may have problems with updatedb not indexing home as root.

Answer (score 1):

You can bookmark the folder you want searchable via Nautilus. Just open Nautilus, select your folder and press Ctrl+D or go to Bookmarks > Add Bookmark in the menu. It should then appear under Favorite Folders along with the defaults in Unity's file search, and the files within it should also become searchable.